# Pop up appears on website when using selenium in Python but not when I manually go to the website

Tags: python, selenium, web-scraping, webautomation

Every time I try to enter footaction.com using Selenium in Python the website displays a pop up with nothing to click stopping me from interacting with the website.

However, when I enter the website manually it doesn't display this pop up and just has the regular website as is. Can it tell I'm using selenium and or a remote automated browser? How can I hide that I'm using selenium so I don't get this pop up?

```
from selenium import webdriver

driver = webdriver.Firefox()
driver.get('https://www.footaction.com/')
```

Comment: As far as I know, the remote site shouldn't be able to tell that you're using Selenium.  Do you use the same browser (Firefox) for manual access?

Comment: Yes. I use firefox for both manual and script browsing.

Comment: Perhaps the javascript code on the page might contain clues as to how it decides to display the popup.

Comment: If you open this site manually in incognito mode, does it show the pop-up? If it does, it means that the site uses cookies or something like that, and it shows this pop-up only on the first use. If it doesn't, it could be that the website uses some techniques to detect that it's used by Selenium. In theory the website shouldn't knows that, but there are techniques that sites use to block scrapers.

Comment: You can't close the pop-up?  What's the HTML look like for the pop-up?

Comment: did you ever figure out this problem?